# How can I change bar color of jquery easyPiechart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Recently my html guy implemented piechart using jquery plug -in name as easyPieChart just like in the following way.

[image]

html code:

```
 <span class="chart pull-right" data-percent="45" id="_percentUpdate">
<div class="flip-container">
  <div class="flipper" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flipped')" id="conserHoursFlip">
   <div class="front percent"></div>
   <div class="back percent"></div>
  </div>
</div>                                              
<span>
```

I want to change dynamically bar color through JavaScript or backbone.js,but I can't able to fix this.

Right now it is in `green` color,I want to change to another color.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: By creating your own...

Comment: I know nothing about this plugin but have you tried to set style="bacground-color:red;"

Comment: I don't want to set `background color`,I just want to set color to `bar`.

Answer (score 15):

What took me some time to figure out is how to make it dynamically show desired color based on percentage. This is what I came up with in jQuery:

```
$('.piechart').easyPieChart({
    barColor: function (percent) {
       return (percent < 50 ? '#5cb85c' : percent < 85 ? '#f0ad4e' : '#cb3935');
    },
    size: 150,
    scaleLength: 7,
    trackWidth: 5,
    lineWidth: 5,

    onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
       $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
    }
});
```

This is the example of how it would look like in case you have more than one Chart Pie:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've been trying to figure this out myself and after some fooling around this seems to be working for me.

```
$('#your_chart').data('easyPieChart').options.barColor = '#0033CC';
```

Answer (score 2):

for dynamic change of barColor use this:

**in your HTML:**

```
<span class="easyChart" data-percent="20" data-barcolor="ffdc00"></span>
```

**in your js:**

```
$('.easyChart').easyPieChart({
    barColor: function (percent) {
        barColor = '#767676'; // this is default barColor
        if($(this.el).data('barcolor')) {
            barColor = '#' + $(this.el).data('barcolor')
        }
        return barColor;
    },
    trackColor: '#c7c7c7',
});
```

You can change trackColor also

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation on the plugin homepage:
http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/

When you initialize the plugin with jQuery, you can set custom parameters like `barColor`.

So instead of the default:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
        //your configuration goes here
    });
});
</script>
```

You can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
        barColor: '#000'
    });
});
</script>
```

It's really not that hard. Try reading the documentation.

Comment: I want to assign `barcolor` dynamically,for that I tried following way. `$('#biz0_loc0_percentUpdate').easyPieChart({barColor: 'red'});`.even it's not working.

Comment: On the same documentation page the author explains how to update the chart. However, I don't think you can update the color, only the data. Here is the code to update the data: `$('#biz0_loc0_percentUpdate').data('easyPieChart').update(Math.floor(100*Math.random()));` -- maybe the color information is stored in `$('#biz0_loc0_percentUpdate').data('barColor')` and you can edit that value. I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

**Snippet :**

```
barColor: function (percent) {
   return (percent < 50 ? 'rgba('+(92+Math.ceil(148/50*percent))+','+(184-Math.ceil(11/50*percent))+','+(92-Math.ceil(14/50*percent))+',1)' : 
   percent < 100 ? 'rgba('+(240-Math.ceil(37/50*(percent-50)))+','+(173-Math.ceil(116/50*(percent-50)))+','+(78-Math.ceil(25/50*(percent-50)))+',1)' : 
   'rgba(203,57,53,1)');
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate from red to green, you can use this :

```
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
        barColor: function (percent) {
            return 'hsl(' + (Math.round(percent) * 1.2) + ', 100%, 35%)';
        },
        animate: {
            duration: 2000, 
            enabled: true,
        },
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent)); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do something like this to get dynamic colours to your pie chart.
Assue your dynaVal range between 0 and 50.
Preset some colors to get dynamic colors.

```
var dynaColorsSet = [
                     "#FFFFFF", // red
                     "#070AEB", // blue
                     "#1DEB07", // green
                     "#FAF211", // yellow
                     "#F76F30" // orange
                    ];

$('#chart').easyPieChart({
            barColor: function(dynaVal) { // dynaVal (can be int/float) is the dynamic value that keep changing
                    var clr = function(dynaColorsSet, dynaVal){
                        var defColor = dynaColorsSet[0];
                            if(dynaVal <= 20){
                                defColor = dynaColorsSet[1];
                            }else if(dynaVal <= 30){
                                defColor = dynaColorsSet[2];
                            }else if(dynaVal >= 30 && dynaVal < 40){
                                defColor = dynaColorsSet[3];
                            } else if(dynaVal >= 40){
                                defColor = dynaColorsSet[4];
                            }
                        }
                        return defColor;
                    };
                    return clr(dynaColorsSet, dynaVal); // this line returns the final
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my EasyPieChart function to change the pie chart based on the percent. This will cause the color to get more Red as it nears completion.

```js
    var chartColors =  function(percent) {
      var dynaColorsSet = ['#fcfcad', '#F8F933', '#FACC00', '#FB6600', '#FB9900', '#FB4800', '#CB0A0A', '#960808'];
      if (percent <= 5) {
        return dynaColorsSet[0];
      } else if (percent <= 15) {
        return dynaColorsSet[1];
      } else if (percent <= 30) {
        return dynaColorsSet[2];
      } else if (percent <= 45) {
        return dynaColorsSet[3];
      } else if (percent <= 60) {
        return dynaColorsSet[4];
      } else if (percent <= 75) {
        return dynaColorsSet[5];
      } else if (percent <= 85) {
        return dynaColorsSet[6];
      } else if (percent > 95) {
        return dynaColorsSet[7];
      }
    };

    $scope.options = {
      size: 50,
      animate:{
        duration:3000,
        enabled:true
      },
      barColor: chartColors,
      scaleColor: false,
      lineWidth: 5,
      lineCap: 'circle'
    };
```